# EXPORT command not found

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell, unix

I have a simple shell file I want to source variables from, the contents of the file are below

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION=1
BUILD=2
```

I used scp to bring the file over from a windows computer to a linux one.

When I try `source ./version.sh` I get the following errors

> ./version.sh: line 1: EXPORT: command not found
>
> ./version.sh: line 2: EXPORT: command not found

If I simply touch a new version.sh and manually write in the files and source the file then it works.

Why does it not work when i scp the file over and run source?

Comment: Could it be, that if you wrote the script on Windows it has CRLF line endings and when you write it on Linux it has the correct LF-only line endings that bash wants? ;)

Comment: @Cobra_Fast I tried running dos2unix on the file in the linux computer and then sourcing it but it still fails

Comment: Alrighty then, open the file you copied over on Linux and make sure there's actually the code you posted here in there. It almost sounds like you literally wrote `EXPORT` into it.

Comment: The internal bash command is `export` , not `EXPORT`

Answer (score 1):

The correct command syntax is `export`. It's also possible that `bash` isn't where you think it is, use `env` to find it - like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export VERSION=1
export BUILD=2
```

Comment: The shebang being wrong won't impact a file that's sourced as opposed to executed.